# Getting runtime error when include cthreads lib in Lazarus/free pascal

Tags: linux, freepascal, lazarus

I'm trying to code a multithread application in Lazarus/free pascal, but I've noticed that when I include the "cthreads" lib (always the first line of my project.lpr file), on some Linux distros, I get a runtime error when running the application. I believe it's some broken library. However, I don't know how to identify it. Could you help me?

project1.lpr:

```
program project1;

uses
  cthreads,
  cmem;

begin
  writeln('test');
end.
```

error:

```
[root@dockerinaja /]# ./project1
Runtime error 203 at $0000000000418D5C
  $0000000000418D5C
  $000000000040086D
```

ldd ./project1:

```
[root@dockerinaja /]# ldd /project1
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc43fbd000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f359ff5e000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f359ff58000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f359fd92000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f359ff8b000)
```

Comment: Put cmem first.

Comment: Putting cmem first and without cmem I'm getting this error:
Runtime error 216 at $000000000042A410
  $000000000042A410
  $000000000040086D

Comment: RTE 203 is a heap overflow. If your container has limitations on memory, try to play with them.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I had a very old version of Free Pascal. I just updated to version 3.2.0 and it fixed my problem. Thanks.